# Design mode in SQL for TFS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, tfs

I am using TFS for version control of my SQL, but I can't seem to figure out how to create tables through VS 2010 in design mode.  I usually design the table in SSMS and then create the script to a query window or clipboard and paste the script in the query window in VS 2010.

Comment: Are you using a Database Project to manage the SQL Source control?

Comment: @MikeDouglasDev - Yes, I am using a Database Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a designer in Visual Studio 2010 but there is in the SSDT (Visual Studio 2012 Database Projects)

Here is a previous post about it.
[Is there a table designer for VS2010 database project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610316/is-there-a-table-designer-for-vs2010-database-project)

Here is a link on how to use it in SSDT (If you are going to use this, make sure you download the PowerTools to get the Schema View and other features)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272680(v=vs.103).aspx